# Memoir `\sourceatright` giving error with reledpar

Tags: errors, memoir, reledmac, reledpar

I am unable to understand why this error pops. Both sourceatright and flushright fails.

```
!Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.32 \sourceatright{Book 1}
```

*This is MWE*

```
\documentclass[9pt,a6paper]{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%reledmac and reledpar optons%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[nocritical,noeledsec,noend,noledgroup,nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar} 

%%%%%%%%POLYGLOSSIA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

%%%%%%%%FLUSH RIGHT wrapper command%%%%%%%
\newcommand\fright[1]{%
{\begin{flushright} #1 \end{flushright}}%
}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\numberlinefalse

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
   \begin{english}
    \begingroup
     \beginnumbering
      \autopar


verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse
\sourceatright{Book 1}

verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse
\fright{Book 2}

    \endnumbering
   \endgroup
  \end{english}
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
   \begin{french}
    \begingroup
     \beginnumbering
      \autopar

verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset
\sourceatright{Book 1}

verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset
\fright{Book 2}


      \endnumbering
     \endgroup
   \end{french}
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must the optional argument of \pstart to avoid problem when typesetting not classical paragraphed text.

```
\documentclass[9pt,a6paper]{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%reledmac and reledpar optons%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[nocritical,noeledsec,noend,noledgroup,nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar} 

%%%%%%%%POLYGLOSSIA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

%%%%%%%%FLUSH RIGHT wrapper command%%%%%%%
\newcommand\fright[1]{%
{\begin{flushright} #1 \end{flushright}}%
}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\numberlinefalse

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
   \begin{english}
     \beginnumbering

\pstart
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse
\pend[\sourceatright{Book 1}]
\pstart
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse\\
verse verse verse verse
\pend[\fright{Book 2}]

    \endnumbering

  \end{english}
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
   \begin{french}

     \beginnumbering

\pstart
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset
\pend[\sourceatright{Book 1}]
\pstart
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset\\
verset verset verset verset
\pend[\fright{Book 2}]


      \endnumbering
   \end{french}
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Note also the following points:
- You don't need to ad `\begingroup` … `\endgroup`
- As you typeset verse, you should use `stanza` and related command instead of manually insert `\\`. Please read the handbook for this point.